# Может ли модератор, снятый с должности (demodded), снова баллотироваться на выборы модераторов?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, выборы, правила

Может ли модератор, снятый с должности (demodded), снова баллотироваться на выборы модераторов? Зависит ли это от чего-то? Вероятно, он может податься на выборы по истечению какого-то срока?

**P.S.** Вопрос просто out of curiosity. ;)

Comment: может, пример тому Бармалей

Comment: @Grundy так он же сам ушёл.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а какая разница?

Comment: @Grundy Ну, я думаю большая... Выгоняют за нарушение, а уходят так просто.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Нет, не может: [What is the process for a moderator to request reinstatement or appeal a removal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/)

> Pro-tem moderators [...] should nominate themselves as a candidate in a future election if they wish to return to their previous position, provided they stepped down from it voluntarily. Moderators (pro-tem or otherwise) who were removed for any other reason are ineligible for nominating themselves in an election, and must complete this process to become a moderator again

Модераторы, снятые с должности не по своей воле, не могут просто так баллотироваться на выборах, и должны пройти [процесс восстановления](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/). В ходе процесса восстановления сотрудники SE, совещаясь с модераторами, решают, восстановить модератора в должности сразу, разрешить ему снова пройти выборы, или вовсе закрыть для него эту возможность:

> Possible Outcomes
>
> There are several final outcomes for each section in this process. They are:
>
> - Reinstate with no preconditions - For cases where the former moderator stepped down voluntarily or by inactivity and they have had no concerning behavior in the interim.
> - Reinstate with preconditions - For cases where reinstatement is allowed as long as the former moderator agrees to follow guidelines specified by one or more of the groups involved in the process.
> - Reinstate with removal expunged - For involuntary removals where it is found in the course of examination that the removal was invalid and the former moderator was not at fault. The CLT will always need to approve this recommendation.
> - Do not reinstate, but can run in election on any site - For cases where there is a barrier to reinstatement immediately but there is nothing generally preventing the former moderator from becoming a moderator again in the future.
> - Do not reinstate, and can’t run in election on any site - For cases where there are outstanding concerns. The former moderator will need to apply for reinstatement again in the future if they wish to be reinstated or be allowed to run in an election. In extreme cases, the moderator may be permanently banned.

Comment: Процесс такой процесс. По нему все наши добровольно ушедшие модераторы всегда могут попросить ромб назад, и сразу же его получат. Отставка ненастоящая!

Comment: @PashaPash это откуда такой вывод про "сразу же его получат"?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ "Reinstate with no preconditions - For cases where the former moderator stepped down voluntarily or by inactivity and they have had no concerning behavior in the interim.". Главное не разозлить перед этим никого из текущих модов, чтобы не было concerning behavior :)

Comment: @PashaPash понятно. В текущем ответе эта часть текста связана с ситуацией "снятые с должности не по своей воле", поэтому сразу не заметил.